# How is a service started by the android system?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

If I extend the **`NotificationListenerService`** of the android system, how is it called if I use the following `intent-filter` in the manifest:

> action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService"

Does the system call it using the `startService()` method? It surely isn't called using the `bindService()` method is it? After all my service that `extends NotificationListenerService` stands alone, it isn't bound to any `activity`.

So providing that it is started using `startService()`, the `onStartCommand()` method should be called each time a notification arrives in the status bar, right?

Is it also possible for me to close/destroy/kill my service that `extends NotificationListenerService`? So that it doesn't run until a new notification arrives, which would call it again through the action in the `intent-filter`mentioned above? This in return would call the `onCreate()` method of my `service`.

Would appreciate some help here, thanks :)